# Converting iterative function to recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to convert this iterative function into a recursive function. The function accepts an integer x and list of integers. The for loop removes an element of the list

```py
def function(x, arr):
  for v in arr:
    if v % x == 0:
      arr.remove(v)
  return arr
```

I tried doing this but it seems it does not work:

```
out = []
def removeMultiples(x, arr):
  if len(arr) < 1:
    return arr
  else:
    if arr[0] % x == 0:
      out.append(arr[0])
      return out + removeMultiples(x, arr[1:])
    else:
      return out + removeMultiples(x, arr[1:])
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, the original loop does not work either. It will skip consecutive target elements

Comment: Just return a new list (with a list comprehension).

Comment: Or iterate, but from the back.

Comment: Are you doing this to avoid the error, or to fulfill an assignment?

Comment: A piece of advice that doesn't solve your problem: never iterate over an array that you will be modifying within the loop. It NEVER ends well.

Comment: @navneethc. That's simply not true. Just be careful and understand what you're doing.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Okay, I was exaggerating for effect, but it's generally not a good idea.

Comment: Don't use recursion for linear iteration in CPython. It's not a functional language and doesn't support tail calls, so even a list of 1000 elements will blow the stack. Also, please avoid mutating globals. The result `out` should be defined inside the function and returned. Otherwise, the function is strongly coupled to the global scope and non-idempotent, basically bugs waiting to happen. You can use a parameter or a nested function to scope that properly.

Comment: What you say your function does and what the code implies are completely different. The code is trying to remove all multiples of x from the array...  Please clarify your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iterative version of this function could use a list comprehension

```
def function(x, arr):
    return [i for i in arr if i % x != 0]
```

and the recursive version could look something like this

```
def removeMultiples(x, arr):
    if not arr:
        return []
    current, rest = arr[0], arr[1:]
    if current % x != 0:
        return [current] + removeMultiples(x, rest)
    else:
        return removeMultiples(x, rest)
```

for example

```
>>> values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> function(2, values)
[1, 3, 5, 7]
>>> removeMultiples(2, values)
[1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Note that both of these versions create and return a new list, rather than removing elements from your existing list.

Comment: While this does answer the question, the recursive code can't handle lists of more than a measly 1000 elements, is quadratic, has more overhead and is harder to understand and maintain than the LC. Great example of why not to use recursion in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your function process the first element and recurse for the rest until there are no more elements in the list.

```
def removeMultiples(x,arr):
    return arr[:1]*bool(arr[0]%x) + removeMultiples(x,arr[1:]) if arr else []

r = removeMultiples(3,[2,5,6,4,12,7])
print(r)
[2, 5, 4, 7]
```

If you prefer a more elaborate solution that avoids Python's recursion depth limit and doesn't make copies of the list, you can work with subranges and split the list down the middle to recurse twice, eliminating multiples of x on the left and right side. Then put the two cleaned up sides together:

```
def removeMultiples(x,arr,start=0,end=None):
    if end is None: end = len(arr)
    if end-start <= 1: 
        return arr and arr[start:end]*bool(arr[start]%x)
    mid = (start+end)//2
    return removeMultiples(x,arr,start,mid) + removeMultiples(x,arr,mid,end)
```